# Flask-Admin upload and insert in database automatically

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

My user is modeled in SQLAlchemy as:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url_pic = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    (...)
```

And I want to add the user to the database in Flask-Admin in such a way that when I create the user, I can upload directly the photo and the destination url is parsed and passed for the url_pic field in the database.

I already can add users and upload photos (well explain at https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/ ), but couldn't find any information on how to merge the add user and photo uploading in the same view.

Any clue ?

Comment: How are you adding users and uploading photo ? Are you using 2 different views ? can you share some code ?

Comment: My Admin panel's views are like this: http://pastebin.com/9J6pEA0Z . As you can imagine, it will render a separate view for Content and FileUpload (which I want to merge, so that when I add a content the url will be the same as the uploaded file) Thnks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify your model to look like this:

```
class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'users'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   url_pic = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
   pic = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
   ...
```

Now you should subclass `ModelView` from `flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla`. Then you add an instance of that subclass to the Admin instance. The following source code could help you to get the point.

```
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.admin.form.upload import FileUploadField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
import imghdr

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class UserAdminView(ModelView):

   def picture_validation(form, field):
      if field.data:
         filename = field.data.filename
         if filename[-4:] != '.jpg': 
            raise ValidationError('file must be .jpg')
         if imghdr.what(field.data) != 'jpeg':
            raise ValidationError('file must be a valid jpeg image.')
      field.data = field.data.stream.read()
      return True

   form_columns = ['id','url_pic', 'pic']
   column_labels = dict(id='ID', url_pic="Picture's URL", pic='Picture')

   def pic_formatter(view, context, model, name):
       return 'NULL' if len(getattr(model, name)) == 0 else 'a picture'

   column_formatters =  dict(pic=pic_formatter)
   form_overrides = dict(pic= FileUploadField)
   form_args = dict(pic=dict(validators=[picture_validation]))

admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(UserAdminView(User, db.session, category='Database Administration'))
...
```

Here you can find the docs for `ModelView`: [link here](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/)
I hope this can help someone!

Comment: `pic` in `User` class should be a string with a path name, otherwise if this becomes a large project, storing lots of `LargeBinary` in a database can get pretty expensive.